# decode base64 does not give a correct original GUID

Tags: c#

I have a string GUID I need to decrease its length from 36 to max 30,the problem is I need to parse to to GUID first :

```
var messageID = Guid.Parse("95ec6174-1d10-4348-a126-faeeb3a026dc");
```

it gives me a correct GUID but when I convert to base 64 and short it,Im getting a short string out of it but when i decoce that string it give me something weird!

```
var shortedGuid= System.Convert.ToBase64String(messageID.ToByteArray());
```

the result from above line is:

```
dGHslRAdSEOhJvrus6Am3A==
```

when i decode it I get :

```
taHC&&
```

any help will be appreacited

Comment: Thats your GUID as bytes. Pass it to `new GUID`.

Comment: @tkausl thanks a million,it works,to be honest did not know that

Comment: just a matter of debugging. Compare the values of `messageID.ToByteArray()` with the result of `System.Convert.FromBase64String(shortedGuid);` they're identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be doing something wrong then converting from the base64 string.
Use `Convert.FromBase64String()` to convert from string to byte array, then pass the byte array to the Guid constructor:

```
Guid originalGuid = Guid.Parse("95ec6174-1d10-4348-a126-faeeb3a026dc");
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(originalGuid.ToByteArray());
byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

// Pass the byte[] to Guid constructor.
// The result is a Guid = 95ec6174-1d10-4348-a126-faeeb3a026dc
Guid decodedGuid = new Guid(decoded);
```